Resolving Import Issue in .py File When Package is Already Installed and Works from Terminal
I have a python script that, when opened in VSCode or any other code editor, fails to import the arch package. After making sure that it was downloaded and that I wasn't running in any virtual environment, I tried running the script from terminal with python ./file.py. To my surprise, no error was reported and the segment of code which relied on the arch package ran as expected.
I first tried downloading with conda, then pip, and then finally using pip to download the package directly from git. Not sure if this is important, but running pip list --format=freeze showed that my arch version was 0.0.0 until I downloaded directly from git, where it now displays arch==7.0.1.dev6+g9ced09e. The issue still persists, however.
Any thoughts on where this discrepancy may come from, or how I can go about figuring it out?
Line from my script:
from arch import arch_model
Error message:
Unable to import 'arch' (import-error)
Expectation:
Import would succeed and I would be able to employ the package. This result is achieved when I run python ./file.py from terminal.

add to the top of your script import sys followed by print(sys.executable) and print(sys.path), then run your script from VSCode and from terminal again. Any difference in the output of these two lines in the two scenarios?

Do you have multiple installations of Python in your system? If so, the python extension in VScode and probably other code editors allows you to select the python interpreter that is used.
Maybe the python interpreter which you where using in the terminal is not the same as the one used by the code editors. (For VSCode you can press Ctrl+Shift+P and enter "python: Select Interpreter" to view and select a different python interpreter.)
You can also check the the path of the python command used in the terminal with where python on windows or which python on linux.
